# How do I Calculate dates with Carbon after retrieving a relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get the current user and see all their assigned items, then I want to get the due date for the current user and calculate the difference to today and display assignment is due in 3 days.

How to I calculate the difference between dates after retrieving a relationship?

Here is what I've tried in my Model, Controller and Blade.

Model:

```
public function getDates()
{
    return ['created_at', 'due'];
}


public function getDueAttribute()
{
    $due = Carbon::parse($this->attributes['due'])->diff(Carbon::now())->format('%d');
    return $due;
}
```

Controller:

```
$assignents = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();
$assignents->due;
```

Blade:

`{{$due}}`

Comment: Could you please state a clear problem in your question?

Comment: What does your posted code do?

Comment: The error I get is that: Property [due] does not exist on this collection instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing the property on a collection, hence
either fetch a single instance of `Assignment`

```
$assignment = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->first();

$due = $assignment->due;

---- blade ----
Assignment is due in {{ $due }} days
```

or loop through the collection to access the property

```
$assignments = Assign::whereHas('users', function ($q) {
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id);
})->get();

---- blade ----
@foreach ($assignments as $assignment)
Assignment is due in {{ $assignment->due }} days
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now if I also want the date below can I use something like this on blade {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($assign->due)->format('d-m-Y') }}

Comment: I used Due - {{ $assign->due_as_date }}</p> after creating a function on the model to convert into date format.